# Permission denied while using SpeechRecognition's recognize_whisper() method

Tags: python, windows, speech-recognition, file-permissions, openai-whisper

I'm trying out some of the transcription methods of the SpeechRecognition module.
I was able to transcribe using Google API (`recognize_google()`) just fine, but when I try using OpenAPI's Whisper (`recognize_whisper()`), a temporary file "%LocalAppData%\Temp\tmps_pfkh0z.wav" (the actual filename changes slightly each time) is created and the script fails with a "permission denied" error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\Renato\Documents\Code\projects\transcriber\.venv\lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py", line 42, in load_audio
    ffmpeg.input(file, threads=0)
  File "D:\Users\Renato\Documents\Code\projects\transcriber\.venv\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 325, in run
    raise Error('ffmpeg', out, err)
ffmpeg._run.Error: ffmpeg error (see stderr output for detail)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Users\Renato\Documents\Code\projects\transcriber\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    print("Transcription: " + r.recognize_whisper(audio_data=audio_data, model="medium", language="uk"))
  File "D:\Users\Renato\Documents\Code\projects\transcriber\.venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 1697, in recognize_whisper
    result = self.whisper_model[model].transcribe(
  File "D:\Users\Renato\Documents\Code\projects\transcriber\.venv\lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py", line 85, in transcribe
    mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio)
  File "D:\Users\Renato\Documents\Code\projects\transcriber\.venv\lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py", line 111, in log_mel_spectrogram
    audio = load_audio(audio)
  File "D:\Users\Renato\Documents\Code\projects\transcriber\.venv\lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py", line 47, in load_audio
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100C:\Users\Renato\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps_pfkh0z.wav: Permission denied
```

The code itself is pretty straightfoward:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile("audio.wav") as src:
    audio_data = r.record(src)
    print("Transcription: " + r.recognize_whisper(audio_data=audio_data, model="medium", language="en"))
```

I tried different installations of ffmpeg (gyan.dev and BtbN pre-built packages, and I also tried installing through chocolatey).

I also tried unchecking the "Read-only" option on the Temp folder properties, but the error still happens.

I'm running the script on a virtual environment created with venv, on a Windows machine.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, I also tried various things and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I got it to work *somehow*. The "`recognize_whisper`" in the "`Recognizer`" class in the speech_recognition "`__init__.py`" file there has the line:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".wav") as f:
```

I guess because I run Windows here (yes, I hate it too...), it somehow gets some permission issues.
I replaced it with:

```
with open('test.wav', 'wb') as f:
```

Now, the .wav file gets generated and it runs without error. But also without showing the recognition result...

Addition: after playing around with the speech_recognition some more, I think the whisper integration is just not working?
I tried giving both whisper and google the same audio file:

```
AUDIO_FILE = 'test.wav'

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file
r.recognize_whisper(audio)
r.recognize_google(audio)
```

This gives results for the google recognition but not the whisper recognition (and gets the permission error when I replace the old code in the `recognize_whisper()` method).

But if I try the same with just whisper (see https://github.com/openai/whisper), this works:

```
import whisper

model = whisper.load_model("base")
result = model.transcribe("test.wav")
print(result["text"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gave up on that method and ended up just using the whisper package (which works fine, as you mentioned, so there's probably something weird going on in the SpeechRecognition package).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact issue as you. Based on the documentation the rexognize_whisper should take in an Audiofile instance in the form of AudioData but it’s not working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).